# Unhandled cast exception error

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form1+comodity]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form2+comodity]'.

for this line:

```
comodityData = (List<comodity>)tf.Deserialize(ts);
```

and I'm not sure why. I have never ran into the error before. Can anyone help me out?

Full code for reference:

```
namespace test
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public float Alligor;
      public float Briochit;
      public float Chollonin;
      public float Espitium;
      public float Hydrobenol;
      public float Isopropenetol;
      public float Metachropin;
      public float Phlobotil;
      public float Plasteosine;
      public float Polynitrocol;
      public float Polynucleit;
      public float Prilumium;
      public float Statchanol;
      public float Titanium;
      public float Vitricyl;

      public float AlligorInput;
      public float BriochitInput;
      public float CholloninInput;
      public float EspitiumInput;
      public float HydrobenolInput;
      public float IsopropenetolInput;
      public float MetachropinInput;
      public float PhlobotilInput;
      public float PlasteosineInput;
      public float PolynitrocolInput;
      public float PolynucleitInput;
      public float PrilumiumInput;
      public float StatchanolInput;
      public float TitaniumInput;
      public float VitricylInput;

      public float costofAlligor;
      public float costofBriochit;
      public float costofChollonin;
      public float costofEspitium;
      public float costofHydrobenol;
      public float costofIsopropenetol;
      public float costofMetachropin;
      public float costofPhlobotil;
      public float costofPlasteosine;
      public float costofPolynitrocol;
      public float costofPolynucleit;
      public float costofPrilumium;
      public float costofStatchanol;
      public float costofTitanium;
      public float costofVitricyl;

      public double totalCost;

      public class comodity
      {
         public float comodityPrice;
      }

      private List<comodity> comodityData = new List<comodity>();
      private comodity o1 = null;
      private comodity o2 = null;
      private comodity o3 = null;
      private comodity o4 = null;
      private comodity o5 = null;
      private comodity o6 = null;
      private comodity o7 = null;
      private comodity o8 = null;
      private comodity o9 = null;
      private comodity o10 = null;
      private comodity o11 = null;
      private comodity o12 = null;
      private comodity o13 = null;
      private comodity o14 = null;
      private comodity o15 = null;

      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         o1 = new comodity();
         o2 = new comodity();
         o3 = new comodity();
         o4 = new comodity();
         o5 = new comodity();
         o6 = new comodity();
         o7 = new comodity();
         o8 = new comodity();
         o9 = new comodity();
         o10 = new comodity();
         o11 = new comodity();
         o12 = new comodity();
         o13 = new comodity();
         o14 = new comodity();
         o15 = new comodity();

         comodityData.Add(o1);
         comodityData.Add(o2);
         comodityData.Add(o3);
         comodityData.Add(o4);
         comodityData.Add(o5);
         comodityData.Add(o6);
         comodityData.Add(o7);
         comodityData.Add(o8);
         comodityData.Add(o9);
         comodityData.Add(o11);
         comodityData.Add(o12);
         comodityData.Add(o13);
         comodityData.Add(o14);
         comodityData.Add(o15);

         FileStream ts = new FileStream("comoditys.dat", FileMode.Open);
         BinaryFormatter tf = new BinaryFormatter();
         comodityData = (List<comodity>)tf.Deserialize(ts);
         ts.Close();

         if (comodityData != null)
         {
            if (comodityData.Count > 0)
               Alligor = comodityData[0].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 1)
               Briochit = comodityData[1].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 2)
               Chollonin = comodityData[2].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 3)
               Espitium = comodityData[3].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 4)
               Hydrobenol = comodityData[4].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 5)
               Isopropenetol = comodityData[5].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 6)
               Metachropin = comodityData[6].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 7)
               Phlobotil = comodityData[7].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 8)
               Plasteosine = comodityData[8].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 9)
               Polynitrocol = comodityData[9].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 10)
               Polynucleit = comodityData[10].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 11)
               Prilumium = comodityData[11].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 12)
               Statchanol = comodityData[12].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 13)
               Titanium = comodityData[13].comodityPrice;

            if (comodityData.Count > 14)
               Vitricyl = comodityData[14].comodityPrice;
         }
      }

      private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // 1st text box input is float
         float tempFloat;

         if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
         {              
            AlligorInput = tempFloat;
         }
         else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
      }

      private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // 1st text box input is float
         float tempFloat;

         if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
         {      
            BriochitInput = tempFloat;
         }
         else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
      }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            CholloninInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            EspitiumInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            HydrobenolInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {               
           IsopropenetolInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            MetachropinInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {               
            PhlobotilInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {               
            PlasteosineInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            PolynitrocolInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
           PolynucleitInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            PrilumiumInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
            StatchanolInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {                
           TitaniumInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void textBox15_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {               
           VitricylInput = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;
        costofBriochit = Briochit * BriochitInput;
        costofChollonin = Chollonin * CholloninInput;
        costofEspitium = Espitium * EspitiumInput;
        costofHydrobenol = Hydrobenol * HydrobenolInput;
        costofIsopropenetol = Isopropenetol * IsopropenetolInput;
        costofMetachropin = Metachropin * MetachropinInput;
        costofPhlobotil = Phlobotil * PhlobotilInput;
        costofPlasteosine = Plasteosine * PlasteosineInput;
        costofPolynitrocol = Polynitrocol * PolynitrocolInput;
        costofPolynucleit = Polynucleit * PolynucleitInput;
        costofPrilumium = Prilumium * PrilumiumInput;
        costofStatchanol = Statchanol * StatchanolInput;
        costofTitanium = Titanium * TitaniumInput;
        costofVitricyl = Vitricyl * VitricylInput;

        totalCost = costofAlligor + costofBriochit + costofChollonin + costofEspitium + costofHydrobenol + costofIsopropenetol + costofMetachropin + costofPhlobotil + costofPlasteosine + costofPolynitrocol + costofPolynucleit + costofPrilumium + costofStatchanol + costofTitanium + costofVitricyl;
    }

      private void textBox16_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         textBox13.Text = totalCost.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: totalCost = costofAlligor + costofBriochit + costofChollonin + costofEspitium + costofHydrobenol + costofIsopropenetol + costofMetachropin + costofPhlobotil + costofPlasteosine + costofPolynitrocol + costofPolynucleit + costofPrilumium + costofStatchanol + costofTitanium + costofVitricyl;
Dude, What are you making?

Comment: That's not the *full* code. Somewhere, you've got a class named `Form1`, which *also* defines an internal class named `comodity`.

Comment: @Edwin ... some pretty nasty code by the looks of things ;-)

Comment: @ Edwin this program will calculate the build cost of a in game item in a MMO game i play

Comment: I am very new to programming and C# so i know some of my code is not optimal but i am trying to learn better ways of doing it

Comment: Polymorphism is a good concept to look into. You have a lot of redundancy in your code defining each of those, erm, elements are they? But they share a lot of common characteristics, which means that they can all be treated as a single unit in a lot of places by your code. Make sure you've got a good book on object-oriented programming.

Comment: well i removed any reference to any class in form1 and i still get the error ?? question code updated as well

Comment: form1 for my code is here : http://pastebin.com/cRy4FJhX i cannot put it in question code to many characters

Answer (score 3):

Define only one class `comodity` and do so outside of any other class.

Comment: okay i understand what you mean but could you point out what i double declared i only see one comodity class?

Comment: You only posted the code of class `Form2`. There is one definition of a class `comodity`. I assume, that inside the code of class `Form1` there is a similar definition of a class `comodity`.

Comment: i figured that since it was a different form that it could not know what classes i used in form 1

Comment: question code updated and error is still there i cant seem to get the site to allow me to post my form1 so here it is on pastebin : http://pastebin.com/cRy4FJhX

Comment: Your class `Form1` still contains a definition for `comodity`.

Comment: oops i think i missed one in form2 testing now and i apologize for not looking before i typed

Comment: every thing that even looks like comodity has been removed from form2 and error is still there

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you cannot do this! In C# you cannot cast a List with one generic type to another.

A simple workaround to this problem is to use the `Cast` Linq extension method:

```
List<Person> personlist = new List<Person>() { ... };
List<object> objectList = personlist.Cast<object>();
```

Comment: Hmm okay all im looking to do is read a list from file and assign its variables to corresponding public variables for use later in the program. i messed it up somewhere i know im just not sure where

Comment: In general, this is the correct answer. In this specific case, Daniel caught the problem. There's no point in having two definitions of the same class, and consolidating them alleviates the need to use this alternative approach.